# Silverlight 4.0 Accordion Template

Tags: silverlight, templates, outlook, silverlight-4.0, accordion

Is their a free template of accordion which behaves like Outlook? When the user adjusted its grid, the accordion item will form an images, stack horizontally?

Comment: Take a look at the Accordion Control included in the Silverlight Toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accordion in the Silverlight toolkit, but it's not quite "Outlook like".
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

You can customize it, but I found it a bit complex. there are some good examples in the Expression Gallery. eg.
http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/site/search?f[0].Type=SearchText&f[0].Value=accordion&x=0&y=0

and I just found this that might help
http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/animatedmenu